# LMS filter always diverges on Cauchy data?

Tags: adaptive-filters, lms

Suppose my data vectors $x$ consist of IID Cauchy values. Does [LMS filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter) diverge for all values of step size $\alpha$?

I tried some [simulations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/stats-cauchy-divergence.nb) and it appears so. Wondering if this is well-known or how to show this.

[image]

Comment: Closing question because it's been asked [on multiple sites on the SE network.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/635234/does-e-leftarrow-e-alpha-x-langle-x-e-rangle-always-diverge-for-cauchy-x)

Answer (score 2):

What would you like it to converge to? I ask, because the Cauchy Distribution has no mean that's well-defined, nor finite variance; the covariance between two (or many) Cauchy variables isn't defined, either :( so, we have no very sensible way of defining the spectrum of your IID Cauchy process, even if the independence actually intuitively suggest the spectrum to be "white".

So, assuming you want the LMS filter to convert your input to an output that converges against the location of the Cauchy distribution, there is a small problem with (weighted) averages of Cauchy-distributed variables: because of the unbound variance, the usual formulation of the central limit theorem doesn't hold, and their sum never becomes (approximately) normally distributed (as a matter of fact, it remains Cauchy-distributed). Sadly, for IID Cauchy variables, it follows that even weighted averages still don't converge – and that will probably be what also hurts your LMS filter :(

You'll have to resort to maximum likelihood estimation (which becomes ugly, as far as I can tell – the PDF of the Cauchy distribution is not easily optimized, even in logarithmized form), or you do something very nonlinear like simply taking a large enough sample and finding the median.

Ad-hoc idea: to keep in the iterative improvement idea of LMS filtering, how about this:

1. at the beginning, your median estimate is bad, because you have no data. You begin by recording the first $N_V$ samples in a vector $V$ and sort it. $N_v$ should be odd and "fairly large".
2. after the initialization, you add a counter $c_+$ for values lying above the maximum element in the vector, and a counter $c_-$ for values lying below the minimum, initialized to 0.
3. for every new sample:

   1. if the sample lies outside the value range in the vector, you increase the respective counter.
   2. if the sample lies inside the value range of the vector, you remove the highest element if $c_+>c_-$, the lowest if $c_->c_+$, and randomly either the heighest or lowest if $c_+=c_-$, and insert the new sample into the vector at its sorted position.
4. you output the new median, as found through $$m = 
   \begin{cases}
   V_{\lfloor (c_+ - c_- + u )/2\rfloor + (N_v +1) /2}, \quad u\sim \mathcal U[0,1) & \lvert c_+ - c_2\rvert < N_v / 2\\
   V_1 & c_- > c_+ + N_v / 2\\
   V_{N_v} & \text{else}
   \end{cases},
   $$
   i.e. you pick the median respecting the "extreme counters" from within the vector, randomizing your choice between two equally centered values if necessary, or output to minimum or maximum if you're at the edges of your vector.

Comment: Taking any finite sample X of my Cauchy data and running LMS filter on distribution formed by sampling with replacement from that X will converge. Larger samples require smaller step-size $\alpha$ in order to converge. So I was wondering whether taking dataset size to infinity will drive $\alpha$ to $0$, or just to a small number slightly 0

Comment: Gut feeling is that no, it cannot converge, but I'll be honest, can't really do the math on that right now

Comment: Don't know if this is on the right track, but off the top of my head, the LMS tuning parameter converges for $0 < \mu < \frac{2}{tr\{R\}}$. Cauchy distributions, to my knowledge, don't have well defined correlation matrices, and they have infinite variance. Taking the trace of the correlation matrix is essentially summing up the variances, so I don't see how it would converge since it's $0 < \mu$ not $0 \leq \mu$. Probably more thorough evaluation is needed though.